# merge two columns to one while insert data from csv to sql server using sql command

Tags: sql, sql-server, csv

At present i insert the data from csv to sql server using store procedure and sql command

using this code

```
 for (int i = 0; i <= ds.Tables["Store"].Rows.Count - 1; i++)
                {
                    cmd.Parameters["@Symbol"].Value = (ds.Tables["Store"].Rows[i].ItemArray[0]);
                    cmd.Parameters["@Date"].Value = (ds.Tables["Store"].Rows[i].ItemArray[1]);
                    cmd.Parameters["@City"].Value = (ds.Tables["Store"].Rows[i].ItemArray[2]);
                    cmd.Parameters["@Country"].Value = (ds.Tables["Store"].Rows[i].ItemArray[3]);
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
```

now i want to merge 2,3 columns in csv and insert as single column

Comment: Not sure why you want to merge two data points into a single column but just change how you populate your parameter.

Comment: please give detail solution

Comment: You didn't give a detailed question, how can anybody give you a detailed solution?

Comment: cmd.Parameters["@Symbol"].Value = (ds.Tables["Store"].Rows[i].ItemArray[2] + ds.Tables["Store"].Rows[i].ItemArray[3]);

Comment: i try the same thing but it does not work

Comment: What do you mean does not work? Did you get an error message? Did your server blow up? I can't see your screen and I have no idea what you are trying to do. You have to provide some kind of details if you want some help.

Comment: Not sure why that solution isn't working for you, but as an alternative you could just execute a stored procedure on the SQL server that transforms your table to what you want. Populate your table just like you're doing, but make that a staging table. Then your procedure can move the data into the final table while concatenating two columns or whatever else you want done.

Comment: you can also try `CONCAT ( string_value1, string_value2 [, string_valueN ] )`

Comment: i get Error Operator '+' cannot be applied to operands of type 'object' and 'object'

Comment: Do you need .ItemArray[0].Value or .ItemArray[0].ToString?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
String myCombinedValue = ds.Tables["Store"].Rows[i].ItemArray[2] + ds.Tables["Store"].Rows[i].ItemArray[3]);

cmd.Parameters["@Symbol"].Value = myCombinedValue;
```

put a stop point in and look to see what is in myCombinedValue.  If it looks correct then maybe the issue is in your stored procedure.  Is @Symbol defined large enough to hold the data?  If it is varchar(10) and now you are sending it varchar(10) + varchar(20).  It will cut it off.

Comment: i get Error Operator '+' cannot be applied to operands of type 'object' and 'object